# How i can fix my virtualenv problem with python?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, virtualenv

I was trying to create my first django project so I installed the virtualenv.
After I typed this into the terminal:

```
~$ virtualenv --python-python3 firstdjango
```

My terminal gave me this error:

```
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR  
virtualenv: error: no such option: --python-python3
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you change the title to be more helpful (what the problem is,  kt that you need help) and format you code right? See [ask] in the [help].

Comment: It should be `--python=python3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using python 3 you should use:

```
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

as documented here: [Creation of virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

[FYI: the problem in your original is the that flag takes an `=` like `--python=python3`]